# lazy react and HOC type,Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<any>

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-hoc, react-lazy-load

## hey guys,I`m new to typescript and I got a little confused, so I will appreciate if you could help me.

as you see under below

### my home functional component

```js
import React from 'react'
import ComponentWrapper from "../../Hoc/ComponentWrapper";

const Home: React.FC = () => {
 return (
     <div>
         this is from Home
     </div>
 )
}

export default ComponentWrapper(Home);
```

### my Hoc

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { compose } from "redux";
import { ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";
import Loader from "../components/loader/Loader";
import { Dispatch } from 'redux'

interface OwnProps {
loader: boolean
}

interface StateFromProps {
base: OwnProps
}

interface DispatchFromProps {
// your dispatch type
}


const ComponentCover = (WrappedComponent: React.FC) => {
return class extends PureComponent<OwnProps> {
    /*------------------------------ state -------------------------------- */
    state = {
    //your state is here
    };
    /*------------------------------ life cycles -------------------------- */
    componentDidMount() {
    // your method for authentication
    }
    /*--------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    render() {
    const { loader } = this.props;
    return (
        <>
        {loader && loader && <Loader />}
        <ToastContainer closeButton={false} style={{ fontSize: "19px" }} />
        <div className="route-wrapper">
            <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
        </div>
        </>
    );
    }
};
};

const mapDispatch = (dispatch: Dispatch) => ({
// your actions
});

const mapState = ({ base: { loader } }: StateFromProps) => ({
loader,
});

const ComponentWrapper = compose(
connect(mapState, mapDispatch),
ComponentCover
);

export default ComponentWrapper;
```

### my react lazy comonents

```
import { lazy } from "react";
/*----------------------------- lazy Loading -------------------------- */
const Login = lazy(() => import("../pages/login/Login"));
const Home = lazy(() => import("../pages/home/Home"));
const NotFoundPage = lazy(() => import("../pages/notFoundPage/NotFoundPage"));

const routePath = [
{
    exact: true,
    path: "/",
    component: Home,
},
{
    path: "/login",
    component: Login,
},
{
    exact: true,
    component: NotFoundPage,
},
];

export default routePath;
```

the error i faced is in the react lazy components and it is:

```
Type 'Promise<typeof import("F:/projects/sitesaz-panel/src/pages/login/Login")>' is not assignable to 
type 'Promise<{ default: ComponentType<any>; }>'.
Type 'typeof import("F:/projects/sitesaz-panel/src/pages/login/Login")' is not assignable to type '{ 
default: ComponentType<any>; }'.
Types of property 'default' are incompatible.
Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<any>'.
Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<any>'.
```

after this error i tried to export ComponentWrapper forcefully with as React component type
but i faced another error and it was in home component :

```
Not all constituents of type 'ComponentType<{}>' are callable.
Type 'ComponentClass<{}, any>' has no call signatures.
```

Comment: Something is up with your `lazy` imports because they are getting type `unknown` when it should be `React.LazyExoticComponent`

Comment: @LindaPaiste there is nothing wrong with his imports or components. The problem is that the components wrapped in his HOC are lacking properties that exist on lazy component type (PureComponent type does have them).

Comment: I come across this problem too. According to your suggestions, I do not resolve it, it does not work

Comment: could you fix it?